# How do I turn 3x4x81x97 matrix into (long) column vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a data matrix (XW_region) that is size 3x4x81x97. Put differently, XW_region is indexed as (day,time,lat,lon), so there are 4 lat/lon grids (i.e. maps, populated by XW_region values) per day for 3 days, leading to 12 lat/lon grids total.

e.g. size(XW_region) = 3 4 81 97

What I want to do is take each XW_region value from each grid cell from each time from each day, and put them into one (long) column vector. From there I want to create a boxplot of the data. I know how to do the boxplot, just need to get the data all combined into one column vector.

Do I need to use the squeeze function to break out each map by day and time?

Thanks!

Comment: `reshape(XW_region,[],1)` should do the job.

Comment: reshape(XW_region,[],1) works great-thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this is a duplicate somewhere, but this is probably what you want:

```
XW_region(:)
```

see more about the column operator [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 2):

As well as @bla's perfectly correct answer, sometimes it's useful to use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) instead:

```
reshape(XW_region, [], 1);
```

(This pattern is helpful in cases where the thing you want to turn into a column is already an expression involving indexing).